# Creating an executable

Tags: command-line, executable

If I open a terminal and type the following then firefox opens with the webapp running:

```
./refine
```

So I have added the following to a txt file, changed the txt file property to an executable - but I do not get the same behaviour - actually nothing happens:

```
#! /bin/bash

./refine
```

So that the pathway is explicit I've amended the above to the following - the files are all in Home:

```
#! /bin/bash

~/Downloads/openrefine-2.6-beta.1/refine
```

When I double click the executable and I choose run in terminal, the terminal opens and then closes straight away. If I just run the script in a Terminal then quite a lot of text is returned to the console before the browser/application open.

Comment: What are your file permissions?

Comment: it is all inside my home - I will amend the question

Comment: Can you show me the output of ls -la

Comment: "no need for sudo" ... when did sudo enter the picture? What does it have to do with the question?

Comment: @muru true - I'll amend the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the refine folder and set the correct file permissions with

```
chmod +x refine
```

You can then launch the executable with:

```
./refine
```

You can run from shell script named `run_refine.sh`, for example:

```
#! /bin/bash

~/Downloads/openrefine-2.6-beta.1/refine
```

You will need to set the executable permission first with:

```
chmod +x run_refine.sh
```

Then you can launch the script with:

```
./run_refine.sh
```

Comment: seems like this is a problem `~/......` if I use `/home/name/.....` it is a lot happier: what is all that about?

Comment: It depends, under which user you are running the command. There is a difference between sudo ./run_refine.sh and ./run_refine.sh. Nevertheless it is better to use the absolute path: /home/user instead of ~/.